# Word that means 'requiring a high degree of trust'

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Something like the reciprocal of 'trustworthy'.

> 'You need to understand how [requiring a high degree of trust] it is
>   to get to know the code to the safe. John has only told three people
>   that code ever because of the power of what's behind the vault's
>   doors'

Almost 'sensitive' but with 'power' and 'responsibility'

> 'The position of babysitter is not a trivial one, as it is a
>   [requiring a high degree of trust] relationship.'

Almost 'sacred' but not quite--it needs to convey the level of responsibility and power that a babysitter has over a child.

> 'A pediatrician must not only be knowledgeable but kind as he holds
>   the wellbeing of a child in his hands, his position is [requiring a
>   high degree of trust]'

Comment: Edit in those words you mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. 'You need to understand the **certitude** one requires to get the
>      code to the safe. John has only told three people that code ever
>      because of the power of what's behind the vault's doors'
> 2. 'The position of babysitter is not a trivial one, as it requires a
>      high degree of **certitude**.'
> 3. 'A pediatrician must not only be knowledgeable but kind, as he holds
>      the well being of a child in his hands. His position is one of
>      **certitude**.'

**certitude**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/certitude)

> n.
>   1. The state of being certain or convinced of something; complete assurance; confidence; certainty; total certainty or greater certainty than circumstances warrant.

Answer (score 2):

The word you need is "**trustworthy**", but you will need to modify your sentences slightly to include that e.g. "The position of babysitter is not a trivial one - it requires **trustworthiness**".

Or "You need to be **trustworthy** to be given the keys to the safe".

Comment: Thank you. I feel 'trustworthy' doesn't capture the potential impact that the person/relationship has to produce greatness or harm with the person who is entrusted. I'm angling toward something like 'custodial' and 'fiduciary' or 'stewardship.'

Comment: @user2723494 If those are the kind of words you're looking for, you need to edit your question so it becomes more clear. As the question is currently written, I would have never thought you had any of those words in mind. *Trustworthiness* does indeed seem the best answer as the question currently stands. (But it seems to me that the greater the potential for harm, the more important trustworthiness becomes.)

Answer (score 0):

The higher the cost or consequence of eventual betrayal the higher the degree of trust is required.You don't have to trust someone that has no way of betraying the trust by hurting you or causing you loss. 
Example: You would lend someone you knew briefly 5 dollars but you wouldn't lend him 100 dollars.

Higher degree of trust we usually assign to people with good **REPUTATION**.
Not only is this word used in context of moral/unmoral lifestyle but it depends of the role of a person in society. **Reputable** science laboratory, school, manufacturer may count on higher degree of our trust.

Answer (score 0):

Intimate fits the bill for most of these sentences.

2 : of a very personal or private nature

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intimate